# Find the column header using intersection in excel 2007?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Is it possible to find the column names of a number of intersections of data.

For instance:

```
name one two three four
Jon   A   B    A     C
Don   B   A    C     B
Ron   C   B    A     C
```

The condition would be find the intersection of "Jon" and "A" and return the column names. So my expected return would be "one" and "three".

Can one do this in a formula or would it be better to use vba.

In either case could you please give me an example of how to set this up?

Thanks.

Update:

I found a formula to return the column name,(ExcelForum):

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(((Data!$A$3:$A$54=$A$28)*(Data!$B$3:$AC$54=$G$25)))>0,INDEX(Data!$B$2:$AC$2,MATCH
($G$25,INDEX(Data!$B$3:$AC$54,MATCH($A$28,Data!$A$3:$A$54,0),0),0)),"")
```

Now I realize that if I have more than one instance where some other column names match the criteria, I would have to iterate through the column names checking the same conditions for each and thereby capturing all the names that meet the criteria.

Any help on how to set this up in vba would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you want to return the column names?  All in one cell, or something else?

Comment: Hi Tim ... Thanks for your question ... I want the column names to be returned one in each cell of a column.

Comment: So as a row or names, or a column of names? Would there be a gap if there was no match in a specific column?

Comment: A column of names ... yes a "", and then a sort should push all the names to top of the column ... thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter as an array function over as many cells as there are potential column names to be returned.

**EDIT**: updated to switch automatically between returning array as row vs column, and to eliminate gaps between column names.

```
Function GetColumns(tbl As Range, rowName As String, val As String)

    Dim arr()
    Dim f As Range, x As Integer, numCols As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    numCols = tbl.Columns.Count
    ReDim arr(1 To numCols - 1)
    i = 1

    Set f = tbl.Columns(1).Find(rowName, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        For x = 1 To numCols - 1
            If f.Offset(0, x).Value = val Then
                arr(i) = tbl.Cells(1, x + 1)
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next x
    End If

    'fill the rest of the array
    For x = i To UBound(arr)
        arr(x) = ""
    Next x

    If Application.Caller.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        GetColumns = arr 'array formula in a row
    Else
        GetColumns = Application.Transpose(arr) 'in a column
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim ... I will be trying this out sometime this week.